# AVAudioRecorder doesn't record on OS X Mavericks

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, avaudiorecorder

In my cocoa application I try to record voice from internal mic. I am using AVAudioRecorder class for this purpose. In code below I setup AVAudioRecorder instance.

```
- (void)setupAudioRecorder {

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = @(kAudioFormatLinearPCM);
    recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = @(16000.0);
    recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = @(1);
    recordSettings[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = @(16);
    recordSettings[AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey] = @(NO);
    recordSettings[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = @(NO);

    recordSettings[AVEncoderBitRateStrategyKey] = AVAudioBitRateStrategy_Variable;
    recordSettings[AVEncoderAudioQualityForVBRKey] = @(AVAudioQualityMedium);
    recordSettings[AVSampleRateConverterAlgorithmKey] = AVSampleRateConverterAlgorithm_Mastering;

    recordSettings[AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey] = @(AVAudioQualityMedium);

    NSString *file = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
                   objectAtIndex:0]
                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".recorder_voice.caf"];

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:file])
        [fm removeItemAtPath:file error:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file];
    NSError *err = nil;

    self.recorder.delegate = nil;
        self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url
                                            settings:recordSettings
                                               error:&err];
    if(!self.recorder){
    // show error
    }

    [self.recorder setDelegate:self];
    [self.recorder prepareToRecord];

    self.recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
}
```

On Yosemite everything works fine but on Mavericks I've got silence. System logs show error when execute **[self.recorder prepareToRecord];** :

AQMEIO.cpp:377 _FindIOUnit: error -66680.

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found an answer. The reason was in the sandbox project setting. I didn't check microphone box in Target -> Capabilities -> App Sanbox. Yosemite ignore this issue but Maverics not.